# JS code for downloading binary files with Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium

I have a code in Java that use JavaScript & Selenium to download binary files. It worked a year ago, but now is just stopped work.

It looks like a feature that my code is relaying on is gone after browser updates. Code works correctly with Chrome, but failing with Firefox.

I'm not JavaScript developer so it's really hard to understand all this changes happen with data types that cause of my code failing.

I have already tried use Bing/Google/Whatever to find solution, but no results.

```
private byte[] retriveBinaryFileContent(WebDriver driver) throws IOException {
    String script = "var url = arguments[0];"
            + "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];"
            + "var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();"
            + "xhr.open('GET', url, true);"
            + "xhr.responseType = \"arraybuffer\";"
            + "xhr.onload = function() {"
            + "  var arrayBuffer = xhr.response;"
            + "  var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);"
            + "  callback(byteArray);"
            + "};"
            + "xhr.send();";
    Object response = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeAsyncScript(script, "https://preventioncdnndg.org/eco-quartier/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2015/09/tree-300x278.jpg");

    List<Long> byteList = (ArrayList<Long>) response;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[byteList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < byteList.size(); i++) {
        bytes[i] = (byte) (long) byteList.get(i);
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

The error message that I got:

> WARNING: Processing of a request was interrupted by exception. Error:
>   Accessing **TypedArray** data over **Xrays** is slow, and forbidden in order
>   to encourage performant code. To copy TypedArrays across origin
>   boundaries, consider using **Components.utils.cloneInto()**.

The problem is clearly in a JS code and not in a Java code.

Could anybody advice me how to fix this problem?

Comment: What is the return value of `driver.getCurrentUrl()` ? At first sight it seems you're not passing a callable, but the return value url, to the script as argument.

Comment: Nevermind. Now I can't see where you're passing the callable in the java code. You're calling the script with only one parameter, the URL.

Comment: Some links that might help: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/Xray_vision
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array

Comment: @Niloct The code was updated in order to make it more straightforward.

Comment: @JohnIV Thank you, I'll check it out.

Comment: So I guess this would work strictly in Firefox: `callback(Components.utils.waiveXrays(byteArray));`. But beware that `Components` is deprecated.

Comment: @Niloct Thank you a lot. I have just checked my code with Chrome and is worked well, but it doesn't work with Firefox.

I have updated code as you advised, unfortunately I got another error message: 

`JavaScript error: https://preventioncdnndg.org/eco-quartier/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2015/09/tree-300x278.jpg, line 1: TypeError: Components.utils is undefined`

I believe is right direction to make it works correctly with Firefox.

Comment: See this page to enable Components.utils: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2765411

Comment: You will have to find a way to set up driver with this config option enabled.